# Collaborative debugging

Tags: feature-request

Something that might be kind of cool for questions tagged html, javascript or css would be enabling [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) type functionality. A user could ask a question, SO notices it's tagged javascript so then the asker could enter some sample html and javascript that demonstrates their question/problem. Then the answerer(s) could each create their own "workspace" to muck around with asker's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Juan said, extremely localized. Having functionality that is only available under certain tags is a bad idea in general. The fact that tags can be switched on a whim makes this even more of an unlikely thing to incorporate.

Comment: If you like what someone said, you could upvote it =P

Answer (score 3):

Too localized, SO is not about specific technologies, but programming in general

Comment: Yeah...I want a sandbox for every language.

Comment: @EBGreen: Now I really want this.

Comment: +1 for the part about it being too localized (sorry for the delay, got taken away from the screen for a few minutes).